# Do I need to continue coming in to the office after quitting?

Tags: professionalism, resignation

I have resigned already and have no responsibilities at work. I worked in consulting so I barely know my manager and we never need to meet anyway. I feel that I should just stop coming in to work and save the travelling time to prepare for interviews.

Comment: This is a good question you should ask your manager or supervisor. I am afraid we cannot really comment on what is appropriate to do in your company.

Comment: What is your notice period? Check your contract.

Comment: Well if they are still paying you they will probably expect you to turn up but as @MaskedMan-仮面の男 says this is a conversation you need to be having with your manager really.

Answer (score 5):

If you're still being paid for your time, you should continue to show up. Unless they tell you not to bother.

If you're not being paid, then you have no obligation to show up for work.

Answer (score 1):

Are still you getting paid? Do you have knowledge transfer that you have to conduct? Did your project manager tell you you didn't have to come in? I've worked at several consulting gigs in the past where I knew the date I was going to be gone before I actually left, and they never said "hey, we don't need you anymore but we will still pay you" but I guess YMMV.